# Python Attribute error when using from main import x

Tags: python, function, import, module, attributeerror

So I have two files: main.py file and a debugModule.py. The debugModule.py file has a class named `Debug()`. This class has a method, `update()`, that I want to use in main.py. How would I do this?

In main I use `import debugModule`, `debug = debugModule.Debug()`, and then `debug.update()` in order to execute this method, however this just throws an error:

```
File "C:\Users\Nisse\workspace\Platformer\src\main.py", line 5, in <module>
debug = debugModule.Debug()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Debug'
```

I've looked around Stackoverflow for answers but I can't get it to work.

How can i use a function from another module in my main.py?
Edit: Turns out I completely messed up the names. Edited again, now they're correct.

Comment: Does `debugValues` import `main`?

Comment: What is `debugModule`? Is it the same as `debugValues`?

Comment: `debugValues` indeed imports some vars from `main`, yes. `debugModule` is the .py file, `debugValues` is a class

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction between "`debugValues` is a class" and "`import debugValues`".

Comment: Oh, oops, apologies. I'm using `import debugModule`. Guess i've been at it too long, haha. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Turns out I'd written them all wrong. 
Now they're correct though, sincere apologies.

Comment: Run the python interpreter from the console. Type `import debugModule`, `debug = debugModule.Debug()`. Is there an `AttributeError`? If so, type `debugModule.__file__` to check the location of the file getting loaded. If the location of the file is correct but you are still getting an `AttributeError`, and if the file is a `.pyc` file try deleting it. This will force Python to re-compile the `pyc` file from the `py` source file (the next time you `import debugModule`).

Comment: There's no `AttributeError`, it appears to be working fine from the console. Also, when I remove the import from main at the debugModule, it works fine. Point is, I kind of need to be able to draw to the screen from this class, because if i'd do everything from the main program loop it'd become huuuge. (I was kinda hoping i could do stuff like GUI drawing and the like in seperate classes.)

Comment: [@Nisse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work): If it is working from the console, but not from the script, then it sounds like there is some error in the script's code which we haven't seen. Please post the first 5 lines of `main.py`, up to the one causing the error: `debug = debugModule.Debug()`.

Comment: @unutbu 
`import pygame, playerModule, debugModule

running = False
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
debug = debugModule.Debug()`

ofcourse this thing has no respect for line breaks

Comment: Please add the code to your original post .

Comment: Try adding `print(debugModule.__file__)` before line 5. Then run the script. What does it print?